# Pass filename from bash to automator action

Tags: bash, applescript, automator

How I can pass variable (on the image its rawtiff.tiff) from bash to further automator action?

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Replace image with text.

Comment: @Cyrus image /w text? Could you explain?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the [linked image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gVrHb.png) in the OP and looking at the **Description** for the **Compress Images in PDF Documents** *action* in **Automator**, it *says*:

> This action will compress the images within the passed PDF documents.

Therefore, you need to pass it the *fully qualified pathname* of the **PDF document** to be processed. So, as the last line in the **Run Shell Script** *action*, you can use the `echo` *command*, e.g.:

```
echo "/path/to/document.pdf"
```

Comment: @S. A., I'd suggest you read my answer again!  It's not working for you because you're passing it a **TIFF** file not a **PDF document**, which is what's required for the **Compress Images in PDF Documents** _action_ in **Automator**! It doesn't compress images **into** a PDF document, it compresses the images already in the PDF document.

Comment: @S. A., BTW If you're actual goal is to turn the **TIFF image** file into a **PDF document** and that's **ImageMagick's** `convert` _command_ you're using, then you can _convert_ the **TIFF image** file into a **PDF document** by using the `convert` _command_.

Comment: thanks a lot! Automators “image to pdf” behavior was not obvious for me.  Tiff2pdf has one problem: it inverts colors and I don’t know why. But if I use preview app to export tiff to pdf - everything is ok. That’s why I thought that automators action can be useful.